# pgadmin4 with SSH tunnel : import not working

Tags: pgadmin-4

using pgadmin 4.14, connection to a remote postgresql through SSH tunnel works like a charm, but importing data does not. 
It seems psql command is not run though the tunnel.

[image]

database setup uses SSH tunnel, and database is defined as locahost.

any insight most welcome.